# Why do I get a warning - JavaScript string return

Tags: javascript, html

```
function getCommonCategory() {
    var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
    var quizType = document.getElementById("quizType").value;
    var moduleNumber = document.getElementById("moduleNumber").value;
    var assignmentNumber = document.getElementById("assignmentNumber").value;

    var category = "$CATEGORY: $course$/Default for " + grade;

    if (moduleNumber == "")
        alert("Enter the module number, please!");


    var shortType = "";
    if (quizType == "Homework")
        shortType += "HW";
    else
        if (quizType == "Classwork")
            shortType += "CW";
        else
            shortType += "QZ";

    category += shortType + "/" + grade + " - Module " + moduleNumber + "/";
    category += shortType + " - " + assignmentNumber + "/";
    return category;
```

I'm doing a project in WebStorm and I have this separate JS-file in which I have this function. However, I keep getting a warning message saying that *Returned expression type string is not assignable to type the*. (it doesn't show the rest)

I also have this function:

```
function getListeningGift() {
    var cat = getCommonCategory();
    var win = window.open("");
    win.writeln(cat);
}
```

and WebStorm says in it: *Argument type is not assignable to type string*

I can't understand what the problem is here. So what is it?

Comment: can u try to set a simple string value to the `grade` variable on the first line of `getCommonCategory` function, and check if the error is still there?

Comment: It turned out that the WebStorm didn't like the javadoc style comment which I put before the function. I erased it and it worked.